# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: (error in tf Cycle GAN)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to code along with [Cycle_gan Tensorflow](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/cyclegan)

I received an error saying:

```
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

My full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-161-bde4fc92c3b9> in <module>
      4     n = 0
      5     for image_x, image_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_horses, train_zebras)):
----> 6         train_step(image_x, image_y)
      7         if n % 10 == 0:
      8             print ('.', end='')

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    694     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    697             *args, **kwds))
    698 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3063     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3064     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3065         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3066             self._name,
   3067             self._python_function,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    <ipython-input-160-538af916a6fd>:28 train_step  *
        total_cycle_loss = calc_cycle_loss(real_x, cycled_x) + calc_cycle_losss(real_y, cycled_y)
    <ipython-input-151-74a790ebcddf>:2 calc_cycle_loss  *
        loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(real_image, cycled_image))
    C:\Users\astro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper  **
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\astro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:388 abs
        with ops.name_scope(name, "Abs", [x]) as name:
    C:\Users\astro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:6492 __enter__
        return self._name_scope.__enter__()
    c:\users\astro\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\contextlib.py:113 __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
    C:\Users\astro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:4176 name_scope
        if name:
    C:\Users\astro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:877 __bool__
        self._disallow_bool_casting()
    C:\Users\astro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:486 _disallow_bool_casting
        self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled(
    C:\Users\astro\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:472 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        raise errors.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError(

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

I have modified the code a bit,

My code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# In[ ]:


# In[118]:


print(tf.__version__)

# In[119]:


import time
from IPython.display import clear_output

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE

# In[120]:


train_horses = []
train_horses_path = 'C:/Users/astro/pythonprojects/cycleGANs/horse2zebra/trainA/'
for image_name in os.listdir(train_horses_path):
    img_path = os.path.join(train_horses_path, image_name)
    img_arr = plt.imread(img_path)
    train_horses.append(img_arr)
train_horses = np.array(train_horses)

# In[121]:


print(train_horses.shape)
# (1067, 256, 256, 3)

# In[122]:


train_zebras_path = 'C:/Users/astro/pythonprojects/cycleGANs/horse2zebra/trainB/'
train_zebras = []
for image_name in os.listdir(train_zebras_path):
    img_path = os.path.join(train_zebras_path, image_name)
    img_arr = plt.imread(img_path)
    train_zebras.append(img_arr)
train_zebras = np.array(train_zebras)

# In[123]:


test_horses_path = 'C:/Users/astro/pythonprojects/cycleGANs/horse2zebra/testA/'
test_horses = []
for image_name in os.listdir(test_horses_path):
    img_path = os.path.join(test_horses_path, image_name)
    img_arr = plt.imread(img_path)
    test_horses.append(img_arr)
test_horses = np.array(test_horses)

# In[124]:


test_zebras_path = 'C:/Users/astro/pythonprojects/cycleGANs/horse2zebra/testB/'
test_zebras = []
for image_name in os.listdir(test_zebras_path):
    img_path = os.path.join(test_zebras_path, image_name)
    img_arr = plt.imread(img_path)
    test_zebras.append(img_arr)
test_zebras = np.array(test_zebras)

# In[125]:


# In[126]:


# Setting image constants
BUFFER_SIZE = 1000
BATCH_SIZE = 1
IMG_WIDTH = 256
IMG_HEIGHT = 256

# In[127]:


# Inputing pipeline:
train_horses = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_horses)
train_zebras = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_zebras)

test_horses = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_horses)
test_zebras = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(test_zebras)


# In[128]:


# Function: random crops
def random_crop(image):
    cropped_image = tf.image.random_crop(image, size=[IMG_HEIGHT, IMG_WIDTH, 3])

    return cropped_image


# In[129]:


# Function: normalize (- for normalizing images to [-1, 1])
def normalize(image):
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    # Note: the image pixel values lie from 0 to 255
    image = (image / 127.5) - 1
    return image


# In[130]:


# Function: random jitter
def random_jitter(image):
    # Resizing the image to 286x286x3
    image = tf.image.resize(image, size=[286, 286], method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR)

    # Randomly cropping to 256x256x3
    image = random_crop(image)

    # Random mirroring
    image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)

    return image


# In[131]:


def preprocess_image_train(image):
    image = random_jitter(image)
    image = normalize(image)
    return image


# In[132]:


def preprocess_image_test(image):
    image = normalize(image)
    return image


# In[133]:


train_horses = train_horses.map(
    preprocess_image_train, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)

train_zebras = train_zebras.map(
    preprocess_image_train, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)

test_horses = test_horses.map(
    preprocess_image_test, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)

test_zebras = test_zebras.map(
    preprocess_image_test, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE).cache().shuffle(buffer_size=BUFFER_SIZE).batch(1)

# In[134]:


sample_horse = next(iter(train_horses))
sample_zebra = next(iter(train_zebras))

# In[135]:


plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Horse')
plt.imshow(sample_horse[0] * 0.5 + 0.5)

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Horse with random jitter')
plt.imshow(random_jitter(sample_horse[0]) * 0.5 + 0.5)

# In[136]:


pix2pix_model_dir = 'C:/Users/astro/pythonprojects/cycleGANs/venv/Lib/site-packages/tensorflow_examples/models/pix2pix'

# In[137]:


# Generator G to transform image from X(horse) to Y(zebra). (G: Horse -> Zebra)
# Generator F to transform image from Y(zebra) to X(horse). (F: Zebra -> Horse)


# In[138]:


# Discriminator (Dx) Learns to differentiate between X and F(Y)(generated horse img)
# Discriminator (Dy) Learns to differentiate between Y and G(X)(generated zebra img)


# In[ ]:


# In[139]:


# Building Generator G
from tensorflow.keras import layers


def Generator():
    # Creating input layer
    input_layer = layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 3])  # (bs, 256, 256, 3)

    # Downsampling
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(
        input_layer)  # (bs, 128, 128, 32)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv1)
    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 64, 64, 64)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 32, 32, 128)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    conv4 = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 16, 16, 256)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv4)
    conv5 = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 4, 4, 512)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv5)
    conv6 = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 2, 2, 512)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv6)
    conv7 = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 1, 1, 512)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv7)

    # Upsampling
    convt1 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 2, 2, 1024)
    convt1 = layers.concatenate([convt1, conv6])
    drop = layers.Dropout(0.1)(convt1)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(drop)
    convt2 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 4, 4, 1024)
    convt2 = layers.concatenate([convt2, conv5])
    drop = layers.Dropout(0.1)(convt2)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(drop)
    convt3 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 8, 8, 1024)
    convt3 = layers.concatenate([convt3, conv4])
    drop = layers.Dropout(0.1)(convt3)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(drop)
    convt4 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 16, 16, 512)
    convt4 = layers.concatenate([convt4, conv3])
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(convt4)
    convt5 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 64, 64, 256)
    convt5 = layers.concatenate([convt5, conv2])
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(convt5)
    convt6 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=32, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        bat_norm)  # (bs, 64, 64, 128)
    convt6 = layers.concatenate([convt6, conv1])
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(convt6)
    # convt7 = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu',padding='same')(bat_norm) #(bs, 128, 128, 128)
    # bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(convt7)

    convt_op = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='tanh', padding='same')(bat_norm)

    return tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=convt_op)


# In[140]:


generator_g = Generator()

# Displaying Generator
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(generator_g, show_shapes=True, dpi=64)

# In[141]:


# Creating generator_f
generator_f = Generator()


# In[142]:


# Defining discriminator
def Discriminator(target=False):
    inp = layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 3], name='input_image')
    tar = layers.Input(shape=[256, 256, 3], name='target_image')
    x = inp
    if target:
        x = layers.concatenate([inp, tar])  # (bs, 256, 256, channels*2)

    # downsampling
    conv1 = layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=4, strides=2, padding='same', activation='relu')(
        x)  # (bs, 128, 128, 64)
    leaky1 = layers.LeakyReLU()(conv1)

    conv2 = layers.Conv2D(filters=128, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        leaky1)  # (bs, 64, 64, 128)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv2)
    leaky2 = layers.LeakyReLU()(bat_norm)

    conv3 = layers.Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=4, strides=2, activation='relu', padding='same')(
        leaky2)  # (bs, 32, 32, 256)
    bat_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    leaky3 = layers.LeakyReLU()(bat_norm)

    zero_pad1 = layers.ZeroPadding2D()(leaky3)  # (bs, 34, 34, 256)
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters=512, kernel_size=4, strides=1, use_bias=False)(zero_pad1)  # (bs, 31, 31, 512)

    batch_norm = layers.BatchNormalization()(conv)

    leaky_relu = layers.LeakyReLU()(batch_norm)

    zero_pad2 = layers.ZeroPadding2D()(leaky_relu)  # (bs, 33, 33, 512)

    last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 4, strides=1)(zero_pad2)  # (bs, 30, 30, 1)

    if target:
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=[inp, tar], outputs=last)
    else:
        return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=last)


# In[143]:


# Setting up discriminator x
discriminator_x = Discriminator()
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(discriminator_x, show_shapes=True, dpi=64)

# In[144]:


# Setting up discriminator_y
discriminator_y = Discriminator()

# In[145]:


with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    to_zebra = generator_g(sample_horse)
    to_horse = generator_f(sample_zebra)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
contrast = 8

imgs = [sample_horse, to_zebra, sample_zebra, to_horse]
title = ['Horse', 'To Zebra', 'Zebra', 'To Horse']

for i in range(len(imgs)):
    plt.subplot(2, 2, i + 1)
    plt.title(title[i])
    if i % 2 == 0:
        plt.imshow(imgs[i][0] * 0.5 + 0.5)
    else:
        plt.imshow(imgs[i][0] * 0.5 * contrast + 0.5)
plt.show()

# In[146]:


plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))

plt.subplot(121)
plt.title('Is a real zebra?')
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    plt.imshow(discriminator_y(sample_zebra)[0, ..., -1], cmap='RdBu_r')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.title('Is a real horse?')
with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
    plt.imshow(discriminator_x(sample_horse)[0, ..., -1], cmap='RdBu_r')

plt.show()

# In[147]:


LAMBDA = 10

# In[148]:


loss_obj = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True,
                                              label_smoothing=True)


# In[149]:


def discriminator_loss(real, generated):
    real_loss = loss_obj(tf.ones_like(real), real)

    generated_loss = loss_obj(tf.zeros_like(generated), generated).numpy()

    total_disc_loss = real_loss + generated_loss

    return total_disc_loss * 0.5


# In[150]:


def generator_loss(generated):
    return loss_obj(tf.ones_like(generated), generated)


# In[ ]:


# In[151]:


def calc_cycle_loss(real_image, cycled_image):
    loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(real_image, cycled_image))
    return LAMBDA * loss1


# In[152]:





# In[154]:


''' generator_g is responsible for translating image X to image Y. Identity 
loss says that, if you fed image Y to generator G, it should yield the real 
image Y or something close to image Y.
    identity_loss = |G(Y)-Y|+|F(X)-X|'''


def identity_loss(real_image, same_image):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(real_image - same_image))
    print(loss)
    return LAMBDA * 0.5 * loss


# In[155]:


# Optimizers
generator_g_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(2e-4, beta_1=0.5)
generator_f_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(2e-4, beta_1=0.5)

discriminator_x_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(2e-4, beta_1=0.5)
discriminator_y_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(2e-4, beta_1=0.5)

# In[156]:


checkpoint_path = "./checkpoints/train"

ckpt = tf.train.Checkpoint(generator_g=generator_g,
                           generator_f=generator_f,
                           discriminator_x=discriminator_x,
                           discriminator_y=discriminator_y,
                           generator_g_optimizer=generator_g_optimizer,
                           generator_f_optimizer=generator_f_optimizer,
                           discriminator_x_optimizer=discriminator_x_optimizer,
                           discriminator_y_optimizer=discriminator_y_optimizer)

# In[157]:


ckpt_manager = tf.train.CheckpointManager(ckpt, checkpoint_path, max_to_keep=15)

# if a checkpoint exists, restore the latest checkpoint.
if ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint:
    ckpt.restore(ckpt_manager.latest_checkpoint)
    print('Latest checkpoint restored!!')


# In[158]:


def generate_images(model, test_input):
    prediction = model(test_input)

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 12))

    display_list = [test_input[0], prediction[0]]
    title = ['Input Image', 'Predicted Image']

    for i in range(2):
        plt.subplot(1, 2, i + 1)
        plt.title(title[i])
        # getting the pixel values between [0, 1] to plot it.
        plt.imshow(display_list[i] * 0.5 + 0.5)
        plt.axis('off')
    plt.show()


# Even though the training loop looks complicated, it consists of four basic steps:
# 
# Get the predictions.
# Calculate the loss.
# Calculate the gradients using backpropagation.
# Apply the gradients to the optimizer.

# In[159]:


EPOCHS = 40


# In[160]:


@tf.function
def train_step(real_x, real_y):
    # persistent is set to True because the tape is used more than once to calculate the gradients.
    with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
        # Generator G translates X -> Y
        # Generator F translates Y -> X.

        fake_y = generator_g(real_x, training=True)
        cycled_x = generator_f(fake_y, training=True)

        fake_x = generator_f(real_y, training=True)
        cycled_y = generator_g(fake_x, training=True)

        # same_x and same_y are used for identity loss.
        same_x = generator_f(real_x, training=True)
        same_y = generator_g(real_y, training=True)

        disc_real_x = discriminator_x(real_x, training=True)
        disc_real_y = discriminator_y(real_y, training=True)

        disc_fake_x = discriminator_x(fake_x, training=True)
        disc_fake_y = discriminator_y(fake_y, training=True)

        # calculate the loss
        gen_g_loss = generator_loss(disc_fake_y)
        gen_f_loss = generator_loss(disc_fake_x)

        total_cycle_loss = calc_cycle_loss(real_x, cycled_x) + calc_cycle_loss(real_y, cycled_y)

        # Total generator loss = adversarial loss + cycle loss
        total_gen_g_loss = gen_g_loss + total_cycle_loss + identity_loss(real_y, same_y)
        total_gen_f_loss = gen_f_loss + total_cycle_loss + identity_loss(real_x, same_x)

        disc_x_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_x, disc_fake_x)
        disc_y_loss = discriminator_loss(disc_real_y, disc_fake_y)

    # Calculate the gradients for generator and discriminator
    generator_g_gradients = tape.gradient(total_gen_g_loss, generator_g.trainable_variables)
    generator_f_gradients = tape.gradient(total_gen_f_loss, generator_f.trainable_variables)

    discriminator_x_gradients = tape.gradient(disc_x_loss, discriminator_x.trainable_variables)
    discriminator_y_gradients = tape.gradient(disc_y_loss, discriminator_y.trainable_variables)

    # Apply the gradients to the optimizer
    generator_g_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_g_gradients, generator_g.trainable_variables))

    generator_f_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(generator_f_gradients, generator_f.trainable_variables))

    discriminator_x_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_x_gradients, discriminator_x.trainable_variables))

    discriminator_y_optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(discriminator_y_gradients, discriminator_y.trainable_variables))


# In[161]:


for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    start = time.time()

    n = 0
    for image_x, image_y in tf.data.Dataset.zip((train_horses, train_zebras)):
        train_step(image_x, image_y)
        if n % 10 == 0:
            print('.', end='')
        n += 1

    clear_output(wait=True)
    # Using a consistent image (sample_horse) so that the progress of the model
    # is clearly visible.
    generate_images(generator_g, sample_horse)

    if (epoch + 1) % 5 == 0:
        ckpt_save_path = ckpt_manager.save()
        print(f'Saving checkpoint for epoch {epoch + 1} at {ckpt_save_path}')

    print(f'Time taken for epoch {epoch + 1} is {time.time() - start}')
```

The error tries to point me in the direction of `calc_cycle_loss`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct. Take a look.

```
loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(real_image, cycled_image))
```

The operation `tf.abs` should only take one value (the second value is for the name of the op). What I think is happening is that since `cycled_image` is being passed as the name of the operation, there are some `if` statements being run to check of `name` is valid. Since it is a tensor, it raises your error. All you need to do is change it to be

```
loss1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(real_image - cycled_image))
```

or something of the sort.